# Why am I scraping Twitter data with R, and the collected tweets are not complete sentences?

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to scrape tweets from Twitter by searching keyword, but it seems that the tweets I collected are not complete sentences. Long tweets only contain half of the whole content. Is there any word limit or sth?

```
library(devtools)
library(rjson)
library(bit64)
library(httr)
library(base64enc)
library(httpuv)
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)

options(httr_oauth_cache=T)

## Twitter authentication
consumer_key <-"**************"
consumer_secret <- "**************"
access_token<-"**************"
access_secret <- "**************"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,
                    access_secret)

tweets11 <- searchTwitter("#iphone11",lang="en",n=2000)
```

[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

twitteR has been archived and deprecated in favor of rTweet.

If you check [the feature comparison in the README for rTweet](https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet) you will see that twitteR does not support extended Tweets.

rTweet's syntax for search is very similar, and it includes the `tweet_mode=extended` parameter transparently for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I encountered another problem when using rtweet. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397035/could-not-authenticate-you-when-using-search-tweets-function-in-rtweet-package) Could you please check it for me?